# Why appear "@" added when copy chars in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm creating a program in C, which receive a file and reverses each line like this:

```
$ cat file
Line 1
Line 2!
Line_3
$ ./reverse < file
1 eniL
!2 eniL
3_eniL
```

But I get an error and I don't know why.

In the program, I made a loop which:

1. Read a line from stdin to a string of 2048 chars.
2. Get the strlen from the read line and made a new string.
3. Copy, char by char, the characters of the string to the new string, in reverse order.

But, running the program, sometimes copy a char and other simbols (@) getting something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8VTx.png

Some strings get @ simbols depending on the length. Here, another example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UKdL.png

The files are in us-ansii.
The code of the program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char string[2048];
    bool final = false;
    while(!final){
        fgets(string,2048,stdin);    // Read line
        if(feof(stdin))
            final=true;
        else{
            int length;
            length = (string[strlen(string)-1] == '\n') ? strlen(string)-1 : strlen(string);
            char reverseStr[length];
            // Loop
            int count = length;
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                reverseStr[i]=string[count-1];
                count--;
            }
            printf("%s\n",reverseStr);
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried changing the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    reverseStr[count-1]=string[i];
    count--;
}
```

Whit pointers:

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    char * pr = $reverseStr[count-1];
    *pr=string[i];
    count--;
}
```

@ Symbol use to appear in the same position.
"Febrero" gets "orerbeF"
"Febrerol" gets "lorerbeF@"
"Febreroll" gets "llorerbe@" (lose the "F")

Here an image of the gdb:
When program is reversing second line "Febreroll"

reverseStr is "llorer" (in **$12**)

In the next iteration:

reverseStr is "llorerb" (in **$14**)

In the next iteration, program copy an "e" and more things:

reverseStr is "llorerbe\221\b@" (in **$16**)

GDB IMAGE IN A COMENT↓↓↓

Comment: THE GDB IMAGE:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlh8r.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs because the code does not take care to insure there is a NUL character at the termination.  The @ happens to appear in the (uninitialized) buffer at the end, then presumably a random NUL is after that.

To fix this, do something like:

```
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            reverseStr[i]=string[count-1];
            count--;
        }
        reverseStr[length] = '\000';  // I added this.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the length stored as a separate count rather than a NUL terminator. So use the length in the format string.

```
printf("%*s\n", length, reverseStr);
```